# What difference does it make if I enable support for video post format?

Tags: post-formats

I am sorry if this is stupid. I can't seem to figure out what special things it does. If I embed a youtube video(embed/iframe) it works for both standard and video format. Surely, I am missing something...

Comment: it will add a class on `post_class()` so you can use different formatting via css.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Couple of things to point out actually:**

1. It will add a class on [`post_class()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/post_class) so you can use different formatting via css.
2. In the case of Post Formats, the taxonomy is `post_format` and the terms are `post-format-{format}`. i.e. `taxonomy-post_format-post-format-link.php` http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy
3. In `single.php` file you can use conditionals to have complete different html for each post format.
4. Hopefully there are more but can remember right now ;)

Comment: Note: it doesn't *have* to be only within `single.php`. Post format-specific output can be used in *any* Loop.

Answer (score 4):

Another nice feature of Post Formats is that [they are a *taxonomy*](http://www.chipbennett.net/2011/01/11/using-wordpress-post-formats-as-a-taxonomy/), which means that you get all the advantages of a taxonomy, and can make many uses of the taxonomy:

- Video post-format archive index page
- Video post-format RSS feed link
- Video post-format breadcrumb navigation
- etc.

And +1 to what everyone else has said, though I much prefer the elegance of this approach, to implementing post format-specific markup using conditionals:

```
get_template_part( 'content', 'get_post_format()' );
```

...which will locate, e.g. `content-video.php` for posts with the "video" post format, and will fall back to `content.php` for posts without a post format.

Answer (score 0):

It just gives you a different way to categorize and style certain posts. In your case Videos (Without a separate template file).